# Failing to extract intent and score with json path from luis response

Tags: json, rest, api, xpath, azure-language-understanding

Hi Folks,
I'm struggling to extract the top 2 scoring intents from LUIS api response adn their corresponding score.
From the response below I need to extract 4 values:

```
{
  "query": "turn on all lights",
  "prediction": {
    "topIntent": "NAME_INFO",
    "intents": {
      "NAME_INFO": {
        "score": 0.0462775342
      },
      "MONTHLY_HOUSING_INFO": {
        "score": 0.0363982953
      },
      "WHAT_NEXT_INFO": {
        "score": 0.03436338
      },
      "ADDRESS_INFO": {
        "score": 0.0306101535
      },
      "SOCIAL_SECURITY_INFO": {
        "score": 0.0280603524
      },
      "SECURITY_DEPOSIT_RETURN": {
        "score": 0.0137537634
      },
      "None": {
        "score": 0.003310648
      },
      "SECURITY_DEPOSIT_INFO": {
        "score": 0.00294959615
      }
    },
    "entities": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to sort the list of intents by their score. Here's a JavaScript example, assuming that your JSON response is saved in `result`:

```js
// Convert result to an array of intents
const intentsArray = Object.entries(result.prediction.intents).map(([k, v]) => ({ intent: k, score: v.score }));
// Sort the array, descending
const sorted = intentsArray.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
// Pull out the top two entries
const top2 = sorted.slice(0, 2);
// Show the result
console.log(JSON.stringify(top2, null, 2));
```

This results in:

```
[
  {
    "intent": "NAME_INFO",
    "score": 0.0462775342
  },
  {
    "intent": "MONTHLY_HOUSING_INFO",
    "score": 0.0363982953
  }
]
```